# New website on new domain after losing old domain

Tags: seo, domains, search-results

I forgot to renew a domain with 5000 visitors a month with around 250 unique articles.

Since someone bought the domain (has not setup any website up) i can only buy another domain and put online my last backup.

Is there anything i can do to tell google that i have new domain with old content ?

Comment: Without being in control of the old domain you have no way of verifying this with Google, setting DNS records or (importantly) redirecting traffic from the old domain. So, "no" unfortunately. +1 for your pain.

Comment: Will at least my old content on new domain still be considered unique ?

Comment: Well, I assume it doesn't exist anymore on the old domain - so yes, it's unique. Presumably the _hosting_ account also expired (domain and hosting linked in a "bundle"?) hence why you needed to resort to backup? (As otheriwse, even without a domain, you should still be able to access your hosting account.)

Comment: Yeah, i have hosting with the website. Backup was wrong word to describe it.

Answer (score -2):

You can login to your Webmaster Search Console and set your preferred domain.  I'd recommend reading this tutorial and setting up your 301 redirect and preferred domain accordingly.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

Comment: You can't set your preferred domain or set up 301 redirects if you've lost control of your domain. (The "preferred domain" feature in GSC is only for setting a preference between www and non-www anyway.)